# Schema for .vssettings files?

Tags: visual-studio, vssettings

I would like to hand edit a Visual Studio team settings file to make a few changes. Is there a documented schema anywhere (either XSD or English prose) for .vssettings files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please elaborate on what you want to edit, and why? I'd be *very* surprised if you came across something  that isn't settable from the GUI. If you need to automate some IDE setup across multiple machines, I'd suggest IDE macros.

Technically - the answer is no.  vssettings files are not validated against any schema, documented or not. 
In case it isn't obvious from the element names how to achieve what you want - you might, for example, set the desired option with the GUI and diff the resulting vssettings with the initial one.
But, again, why would you want to do that?

Comment: In my case the .vssettings file seems to get periodically reset to default, so I'd like a scriptable way to automatically import a backup .vssettings that has all the External Tools that I've added in it.